# How to access hyperlinks in PDF documents in iphone/ipad?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, pdf

How can I access hyperlinks in PDF documents on the iPhone and iPad?

I want to set links on the content of an e-book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following function to put UIButtons on the links in PDF. This will draw Buttons on your UIView. You have to pass your page as parameter. Currently it will draw button with type UIButtonTypeRoundedRect you change afterwards it to custom so it will be hidden. Initially buttons may be drawn other place than link so you need to adjust x/y position according to you requirement.

```
-(void)drawLinks:(CGPDFPageRef)thisPage
{
    CGPDFDictionaryRef pageDictionary = CGPDFPageGetDictionary(thisPage);

    CGPDFArrayRef outputArray;
    if(!CGPDFDictionaryGetArray(pageDictionary,"Annots", &outputArray)) 
    {
        return;
    }

    int arrayCount = CGPDFArrayGetCount( outputArray );
    if(!arrayCount) 
    {
        //continue;
    }

    for( int j = 0; j < arrayCount; ++j ) 
    {
        CGPDFObjectRef aDictObj;
        if(!CGPDFArrayGetObject(outputArray, j, &aDictObj)) 
        {
            return;
        }

        CGPDFDictionaryRef annotDict;
        if(!CGPDFObjectGetValue(aDictObj, kCGPDFObjectTypeDictionary, &annotDict)) {
            return;
        }

        CGPDFDictionaryRef aDict;
        if(!CGPDFDictionaryGetDictionary(annotDict, "A", &aDict)) {
            return;
        }

        CGPDFStringRef uriStringRef;
        if(!CGPDFDictionaryGetString(aDict, "URI", &uriStringRef)) {
            return;
        }

        CGPDFArrayRef rectArray;
        if(!CGPDFDictionaryGetArray(annotDict, "Rect", &rectArray)) {
            return;
        }

        int arrayCount = CGPDFArrayGetCount( rectArray );
        CGPDFReal coords[4];
        for( int k = 0; k < arrayCount; ++k ) {
            CGPDFObjectRef rectObj;
            if(!CGPDFArrayGetObject(rectArray, k, &rectObj)) {
                return;
            }

            CGPDFReal coord;
            if(!CGPDFObjectGetValue(rectObj, kCGPDFObjectTypeReal, &coord)) {
                return;
            }

            coords[k] = coord;
        }               

        char *uriString = (char *)CGPDFStringGetBytePtr(uriStringRef);

        NSString *uri = [NSString stringWithCString:uriString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(coords[0],coords[1],coords[2],coords[3]);

        CGPDFInteger pageRotate = 0;
        CGPDFDictionaryGetInteger( pageDictionary, "Rotate", &pageRotate ); 
        CGRect pageRect = CGRectIntegral( CGPDFPageGetBoxRect( thisPage, kCGPDFMediaBox ));
        if( pageRotate == 90 || pageRotate == 270 ) 
        {
            CGFloat temp = pageRect.size.width;
            pageRect.size.width = pageRect.size.height;
            pageRect.size.height = temp;
        }

        rect.size.width -= rect.origin.x;
        rect.size.height -= rect.origin.y;

        CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        trans = CGAffineTransformTranslate(trans, 0, pageRect.size.height);
        trans = CGAffineTransformScale(trans, 1.0, -1.0);

        rect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(rect, trans);

        UIButton *btnTmp = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; // After testing put here UIButtonTypeCustom
        [btnTmp addTarget:self action:@selector(urlOpen:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x + 78; //I have adjusted this as per my requirement
        rect.origin.y = rect.origin.y + 108; // I have adjusted this as per my requirement
        btnTmp.frame = rect;
        btnTmp.titleLabel.text = uri;
        [self.superview addSubview:btnTmp];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks jennis but i want to on a curl page pdf to set a link at website url but this code is not running in my application.

Comment: This code works on any pdf page. What problem you are running into ?

Comment: thanks jennish for reply .jennish you have example then send me... i have to set a link on this pdf file and i also use in curl page effect on pdf . if u have demo or sample code pls send me link.

Comment: thanks for rpl steipete .  but i can't buy a your Application because i m student and i not spend money in application.and i want to make a a curl effect and navigation on page application for my college project...thanks very much ...

Comment: If you wanna add a curl effect, look into the additions in iOS5, there's a pretty easy to implement PageCurlController addition. Before this, you had to fiddle with OpenGL and the math was also pretty tricky.